# How to install Keras from github on centos 7?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, centos

I'm trying to find a way how to install it from Github.

The Pip works, but still, I want to understand how to install it from Github.

I tried that:

1. git clone https://github.com/keras-team/keras.git
2. cd keras
3. python setup.py install <-- that's an old installation approach.

Now I'm getting en error;

Because there's not such file. Now it's changed to setup.cfg

I don't know how to run it on CentOS.

I tried python setup.cfg install

but get a bunch of the wrong syntaxes which I tried to fix but it doesn't help at all.

```
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# python setup.cfg install
  File "setup.cfg", line 8
    per-file-ignores=*__init__.py:F401
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# vim setup.cfg
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# python setup.cfg install
  File "setup.cfg", line 8
    per-file-ignores=__init__.py:F401
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# vim setup.cfg
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# python setup.cfg install[A
  File "setup.cfg", line 8
    per-file-ignores=__init__.py:
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# python setup.cfg install
  File "setup.cfg", line 8
    per-file-ignores=__init__.py:
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# vim setup.cfg
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# python setup.cfg install
  File "setup.cfg", line 8
    per-file-ignores=__init__.py
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
[root@cloudvpsserver keras]# python setup.cfg install
  File "setup.cfg", line 8
    per-file-ignores=__init__.py
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I edited the question. Can you please take a look

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/keras-team/keras#readme?  You install TensorFlow 2 which will include Keras.

Comment: that's right. The thing is I'm writing an article on how to do it and I want to double-check if this method is outdated or if I can find a working method via GitHub? Also, I tried to install tensorflow2 via git, but it's all comes to creating a python env and then work with pip installation